# $\int_{2018}^\infty\frac{\cos^2(x)}{x^{7/6}+x^{1/6}\cos^3x}$ does this integral converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

This is from an assignment i got, i need to show if it converges and if it converge absolutely.
I believe it diverges and i tried to show it by subtracting a known converging  integral from it, and thus receiving another integral which is easier to show that it diverges, hence the original integral is diverging, because if he was converging than the integral after the subtraction was suppose to converge as well.

The problem was that i could not manage to find another integral which will give me my desired answer.

$$\int_{2018}^\infty\frac{\cos^2(x)}{x^{7/6}+x^{1/6}\cos^3x}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that

$$0\le \frac{\cos^2(x)}{x^{7/6}+x^{1/6}\cos^3x}\le \frac{1}{x^{7/6}-x^{1/6}}\sim \frac{1}{x^{7/6}}$$

Comment: (+1) Much better than what I was trying to do.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks! Much appreciative.

Comment: So in essence it converges absolutley right?

Comment: @MaorRocky Note that the integrand is positive.